# Is it possible to tell MSBuild in TeamCity to use multiple cores

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, teamcity

Apparently the default number of cores MSBuild will use during compilation is 1.

In TeamCity I have tried adding /m:8 to the Command line parameters field in an MSBuild Runner type task to tell the MSBuild compiler to use up to 8 cores to compile the projects within the solution.

(I realise the amount it can do in parallel depends on the dependencies between the projects in the solution.)

However when I look in the build logs I don't see any mention of that parameter?

Is this the right way to do this? Does anyone know if TeamCity supports this?

Note: This is on TeamCity 8.1.5 (build 30240)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the build agent, when the build is in progress, you could login and start task manager, to see if there are multiple msbuild.exe (s).

I don't think that the build logs will have any info about this. What kind of info are you looking for?

Comment: Do you mean what kind of info am i looking for in the build logs?.. I am looking for the command line parameters I provided in the step to check that they are being used.